# Find a single nonzero vector that is in the span of two sets of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

This is a question that I had trouble with on one of my Linear Algebra exams this spring. I would appreciate if anyone could assist me in completing the problem.

Find a single nonzero vector $w$ that is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and which is also the span of $v_3$ and $v_4$, where the $v_i$ are: 
$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}, v_4 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

**My Work**

In order for $w$ to be in the span of $\{v_1, v_2\}$ and $\{v_3, v_4\}$, I must write $w$ as a linear combination of the two sets of vectors.

Would I have to solve two systems of equations to find the value of $w$ and find the similar values? For example: 
$$w = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 2\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}C_1 \\C_2 \\ C_3\end{bmatrix}, w = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\\ -1 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}C_1 \\C_2 \\ C_3\end{bmatrix} $$

Or is there a method to solve this more efficiently?

Comment: Form the homogeneous system $0=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4$. Do Gauss elimination to echelon it. Do back substitution to find a non-trivial solution. Then $w=a_1v_1+a_2v_2=-a_3v_3-a_4v_4$ is one such solution. This method is using that we know that $v_3,v_4$ are linearly independent, which is apparent since the matrix $[v_2|v_4]$ has already there there two echelons.

Comment: General advice: Often times the problems that you find at the beginning of a  linear algebra course are going to have a solution that consists in doing a combination of Gauss elimination and back substitution. Maybe one or two of each. You can try to aim for an interpretation of the problem that reduces to just doing that.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I run into any other problems when reviewing. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$v_1 \times v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$v_3 \times v_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Check that

$$-v_1+2v_2=3v_1+v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I was not utilizing the cross product to solve for *w*